# How do I make my boxes stop making white space?

Tags: html, css

When I try to design my website by adding some awesome info boxes, my boxes stretch out the page and add white space.

Here is a screenshot of the issue (note the space on the right):
[image: Problem]

And here is the relevant code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="Projectbox">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="Projects">
            <p class="TextOne">Projects</p>
            <p class ="TextTwo">Click to get redirected<br>to all of our projects
              <div class="Backgroundsknap">
                 <div class="knap">
                    <p class="Knap2"><a href="C:\Users\Jonas\Desktop\Godlike Games\Projects.html">Projects!</a></p>
                 </div>
              </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.projectbox {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #0C3C60;
    margin-left: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: ?? where is the `class="projectbox"` in your html ? p & P are two different caractere :)

Comment: Are you sure the white space is from your info boxes and not your background image?

Comment: It isnt from my background image because if i remove the boxes it centers

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a body tag somewhere. Try adding the following css to format the body.

```
body {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: I tried to do that but didnt work still alot of white space?

Comment: I feel like it isn't the box that's causing this but it's hard to say without seeing the rest of your html and css. Have you tried commenting out the box's code and ensuring the white space goes away?

Comment: Yes when i comment out the boxes the space disappeares